# Codeigniter restfull api with digest password Issue

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, restful-authentication

I am using Restful api in CodeIgniter. Now I want to give api to third party, so I want to secure that api I am using digest, when I hit the api 
in the browser a pop up comes which ask about username and password.
So I want to ask how to pass username and password in url to that it works. 
Thank you in advance and sorry for the bad English

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer you question but it does provide an alternative.

In my experience with API's you secure them with a HMAC. This is basically a hash that is generated using some data unique to the request, a timestamp and a private key. This hash along with the data used to create it will be passed to your API - NOT the private key - this data can all be sent in the headers of the request. When your API gets this data is uses the unique data, the timestamp and the private key to create another hash. The hash from the header and the newly created one are then compared. If they match you can be sure that the same private key was used to generate them. This saves sending any usernames/passwords over the internet.

I would also recommend that your server is setup to only serve HTTPS, this  will help prevent man in the middle attacks.

This is a library that I have written for this very purpose.

https://packagist.org/packages/mardy-git/hmac

I hope this helps.